# Capturar id de um elemento com click em javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

No *document* há três `<div>`, todas com o evento *onclick* que chama uma função.

Ao clicar em alguma das três, gostaria de capturar o id da `<div>` clicada.

Como posso capturar o *id* desse elemento?

Comment: Implementação inteligente, diminui muito a codificação

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Se você estiver usando JavaScript *inline* (como em `<div id="a" onclick="f()">...`), não dá. Você precisaria passar o id na própria chamada de função. Mas usar JS inline é contraindicado, não só por isso mas também porque é uma mistura de estrutura (HTML) e comportamento (JS).

Se estiver criando o listener do evento por JavaScript, basta usar `this.id`:

```
var div = document.getElementById('seuid');
div.onclick = function() {
    alert(this.id); // alerta 'seuid'
} 
// OU:
div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(this.id); // alerta 'seuid'
});
```

---

Considerando seu comentário que esclarece que se trata de um menu com vários itens clicáveis: **delegue o tratamento do evento** para um elemento mais acima na hierarquia, e obtenha o item clicado do objeto evento que é passado automaticamente para o listener. Exemplo:

```
<ul id="fora">
    <li id="dentro1">aaaaaa</li>
    <li id="dentro2">aaaaaa</li>
    <li id="dentro3">aaaaaa</li>
</ul>
```

```
var el = document.getElementById('fora');
el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert(e.target.id);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Uuv5/

Comment: tipo, na sua resposta você definiu o objeto com o getElementById(), mas eu não sei em qual id o usuario vai clicar, tipo, esses tres divs seriam itens de menu, e eu quisesse aplicar um efeito quando esse item fosse clicado, tenho criar um evento pra cada um?

Comment: Não, tem um jeito melhor de fazer nesse caso. Veja meu update na resposta.

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado. Só uma duvida, na parte nova da sua resposta onde que fica especificado que é para pegar o id dos elementos interiores?

Comment: O `e` é o tal "objeto evento" passado automaticamente. `e.target` é o elemento que disparou o evento (o elemento clicado). `e.target.id` é o id desse cara. E `this.id` seria o id do ul, sempre.